# Marketing Cloud push notification not working - ID check

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush, push, push-notification

I'm using MobilePush in Marketing Cloud to send push notifications to my Android phone and it's not working!

It seems like there are IDs everywhere along the road. Can someone please help me figure out what needs to go where?

**First, Android Java code, on init of MarketingCloudSdk you need to send some IDs:**

```
MarketingCloudSdk.init(this, MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
            .setApplicationId("801a9061-f48a-4053-b838-9962d6aeef2e")
            .setAccessToken("535gar5272p4um77cjw5xvyy")
            .setGcmSenderId("701243172379")
            //Enable any other feature desired.
            .build()
```

- `ApplicationId` - what is this? I've guessed it's the application ID of my "MobilePush" type app in the App Center??
- `AccessToken` - what is this? Again, I've guessed it's the access token of my "MobilePush" type app in the App Center??
- `GcmSenderId` - what is this?? I've guessed it's the "senderId" of my app in Google FCM, under Settings > Cloud Messaging > Sender Id?

**Next, using MobilePush Marketing Cloud, when you add a contact, you need to provide the following 4 mandatory things:**

- `AppId` - What is this? I've guessed it's the application ID of my "MobilePush" type app in the App Center??
- `DeviceId` - What is this? I've guessed it's the deviceId that FCM generates when you call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` in your Android Java code?
- `SystemToken` - No idea what this is or how to get it!!
- `SubscriberKey` - No idea what this is or how to get it!!

Any help on trying to put these pieces of the puzzle together is much appreciated!

I have got some of my assumptions wrong above I am sure. Help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your "send some IDs" guesses were correct.  Details can be found [Create a MobilePush App in the App Center](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/create-apps/create-apps-app-center.html) and [Provision App: Retrieve Key and ID in Google Firebase](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/provisioning/google.html).

Are you manually trying to use the Marketing Cloud APIs?  The SDK will handle registering your contact with the Marketing Cloud servers once the device has received a Push Token from Google.  Optionally, you can set a unique identifier for the contact using the [setContactKey() method](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/subscriber-key.html).

If you're using the SDK, here are some [helpful troubleshooting steps](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html), but from your description, and the most common problem, it sounds like you may not have created your application in the Marketing Cloud's App Center with a `Legacy Server Token` from Google.

Comment: hey man, I still think that's something wrong with my impl, I faced pretty much the same difficulties of Phil. I was able in the end of the troubleshooting steps to successfully call the push notification through curl, but I got the push token from Firebase SDK (which I also use), the systemToken and pushToken within MarketingCloudSdk is always null.
I also tried to set it through PushMessageManager, didn't work. I wonder if I get this changes to prod, if it'll work. Also, I can't find the token I got from firebase into the MobilePush contacts list...